# PFArrayD.cpp implementation Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

So I have my PFArrayD.cpp all implemented and working fine, I just have difficulty understanding how the copy constructor works on it. This is the code for the copy constructor.

```
PFArrayD::PFArrayD(const PFArrayD& pfaObject) : capacity(pfaObject.getCapacity()), //SOLUTION
used(pfaObject.getNumberUsed()){

    a = new double[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < used; i++){
        a[i] = pfaObject.a[i];
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain whats happening in this piece of code ? from start to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems pretty straightforward to me.

It looks like your class has an array member called "a", which size is known with the member funciton getcapacity(), and the used elements are known from getNumberUsed().

So the copy constructor gets the size and used elements of the object to be copied in the first line, calling respectively those member functions.

Then it is allocating the right memory size and doing a straightforward copy of the used elements inside the vector a, which should be the container of the new data.

Is there something you don't understand in particular??